# Saving contents of String Array List when moving to a new activity and returning to the previous one

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, savestate

I have a main activity with 3 image buttons. These act as tabs/categories that pull up 3 different activities when clicked. I have a listview on the home tab which is populated with data pulled of a website. The app allows the user to navigate categories by clicking the tab icons at the top(which pulls up a new activity).

I haves used .putStringArrayList(,) in the onSaveInstanceState and .getStringArrayList() in the onRestoreInstanceState.

My Problem:

When I update the listview on the home tab, click another tab on top to navigate to a new activity, and then return to the home tab activity by pressing the 'back' hard key, the list contents are retained.

However, if I update the list, navigate to a new tab(activity) and then navigate back to the home activity by clicking the home icon/tab(NOT the hard  'back' key), then the list contents vanish and have to be reloaded.

Effectively, it seems to me that even though the user feels he is going back to the prev tab, the app assumes it is moving forward to that tab, and there is some loss of data there.

How do I solve this?

Thanks!

This is my code:

```
int headlinessize;
int linkssize;
ArrayList<String> headlines = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; 

@Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("headlines", headlines);
     savedInstanceState.putInt("headlinessize", headlinessize);
     savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("urls", links);
     savedInstanceState.putInt("linkssize", linkssize);
     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainscreen);

    if (savedInstanceState!= null){
    headlines.addAll(savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("headlines"));
    links.addAll(savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("urls"));
    headlinessize=savedInstanceState.getInt("headlinessize");
    linkssize=savedInstanceState.getInt("linkssize");
    }
            .
            .
            .
           }
```

Comment: It seems to me like you should be using the built-in action bar tabs (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) for this. Then you can use Fragments for each of the tabs, instead of activities, which makes retaining state easier.

Comment: Yes! :) I wanted to do this. I'm a beginner at Android, and didnt know I had to upgrade my SDK to make use of it. Anyway, I started off this way and want to finish it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use PersistentState of app (SharedPreferences)
So make the
onPause() method on your activity and there save SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.put....
```

Then onCreate check for SharedPreferences.contains("key");
and reload data from there with

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.get...
```